# Email client with language translation support for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, email, software-rec, translation

I'm looking for an OS X desktop email client that helps me translate my Japanese work emails into English. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a GUI app you could use a 3rd party software and the OS X services menu. See, for example, http://code.google.com/p/babelfish/ or one of many others found by searching for "OS X Translate Service"

If you use a command line email client (pine, alpine, mutt, etc.) I would suggest you just pipe the body of the message to a command line translator. You could even automate this as part of your fetchmail or procmail scripts so that the translation becomes an official part of the email (emails often already have the same content in plain text, HTML, and multiple encondings, you'd just be adding one more). Note that you could do this via procmail even if reading your email in a GUI client.

A quick search finds two CLI translators, "tw" and "tranny":

- http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/twandgtw/
- http://www.andrewault.net/2010/06/23/linux-command-line-language-translator/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Thunderbird](http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/thunderbird/) with a plug-in like [Quick Translator](https://addons.mozilla.org/af/thunderbird/addon/quick-translator/) or [Translation Panel](https://addons.mozilla.org/af/thunderbird/addon/translation-panel-4698/).